# How do I repair Ubuntu 18.04 after login loop issue?

Tags: 18.04

I started my laptop Toshiba Satellite L755 as usual this morning for work. But suddenly I got into the login loop mode. After reading some tips here

[Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

I tried the shell login mode. After logging in using shell mode successfully, I restarted my laptop using power button forcefully. Because after logging in I couldn't do anything due to my screen keep flipping and change back to boot screen. I noticed there is a Nvidia driver loading line at the bottom. While the boot load screen like 3 seconds, it keeps logging in and same screen for infinite amount of time. Anyway, so, after the forceful power button push, I started the laptop again. Now, it logs in normally. But I think Ubuntu 18.04 is got broken. I have attached some pictures here -

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQcFS.jpg  (cannot attach image here due to first time post)

As you can see that, all the icons are big and there is no sidebar. Also, there is no application menu button anywhere on the screen. The theme changed to white color but it was total dark theme before. My system menu also changed. There were so many options available there.

So, I want to revert back to my old Ubuntu system. This would be a great loss if any files goes missing from my system folders like document or download. As, I cannot see some of my folders created inside the downloads folder.

I tried the Resetter also. I included one screenshot of my terminal with error messages. So, I need a solid repair solution.

So, please help me out. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Waiting for your kind reply.

Imran

Answer (score -1):

Ok. So after waiting to find some answers from here and trying to figure it out from the internet, I reinstalled windows in it. Thanks for letting me post here.

Goodbye.

Imran